# Symfony2: HTML5 Geolocation API in IvoryGoogleMapBundle

Tags: php, google-maps, symfony, geolocation

I'm working on a project that is based on Symfony2. I'm using the [IvoryGoogleMapBundle](https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryGoogleMapBundle) bundle for generating Google Maps. For a map, I need it to be centered on the current user coordinates.

For this I want to use the Geolocation HTML5 API, instead of a server-side solution.

In the documentation of the bundle there is no solution presented for this case.

What is an elegant way of adding this functionality to a google map generated with IvoryGoogleMap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### First generate your map:

We use a service to generate it. But the basic setup for a map is fairly simple.

```
/** var \Ivory\GoogleMapBundle\Model\MapBuilder $map */
$map = $mapBuilder->build();
// any additional config goes here.
// make sure you set the Javascript Variable name like so:
$map->setJavascriptVariable('your_awesome_map');
```

#### Now render the map:

```
{{ google_map_container(map) }}
{{ google_map_js(map) }}
```

#### Finaly you can inject you own Javascript code:

Set up a `javascript` file and include it into your template. In that file your can now do something like this:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(updateMap, error);
}

function updateMap(position) {
    // location determined
}
```

`position` contains the current position like so:

```
position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude
```

use it so e.g. center the map there. You can access the map you generated in the service over your Javascript variable `your_awesome_map`.